# Create a custom time zone

Tags: r, timezone

Is it possible to create a custom time zone in R for handling datetime objects?

More specifically I am interested in dealing with POSIXct objects, and would like to create a time zone than corresponds to "US/Eastern" - 17 hours. Time zones with a similar offset do not follow the same daylight savings convention as the US.

The reason for using a time zone so defined comes from FX trading, for which 5 pm EST is a reasonable 'midnight'.

Comment: It's better to not care when "midnight" might occur, and instead worry about when trading is open for a particular venue.  Then you can use UCT for all timestamps and avoid confusion.  (I speak from experience here.)

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: I am looking to write binary files by currency/day and UTC is not very meaningful in this respect. Maybe I should store them by currency/week, so that the choice of a time zone is not that important.

Comment: UCT is the only thing that is meaningful, when you are gathering data from points around the world.  I agree that determining what is a "trading day" based on UCT timestamps is not trivial, but there isn't a trivial solution to this problem that won't bite you sooner or later.  Probably sooner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are concerned about a specific ”midnight-like” time for each day, I assume that you want to obtain a date without time which switches over at that time. If that is your intention, then how about simply subtracting 17 hours (= `17*3600` seconds) from your vector of times, and taking the date of the resulting `POSIXct` value?

That would avoid complicated time zone maniplulations, which are usually not hanled by R itself but the underlying C libraray, as far as I know, so they might be difficult to achieve from within R. Instead, all computations would be performed in EST, and you'd still get a different switchover time than the local midnight.